# gSoap XML data binding - Possible to auto complete read/write functions?

Tags: c++, xml, binding, gsoap

I am using several XML files each with their own handler class.  Each class has loadXML and exportXML functions that are identical but one line.  I would like to determine a method where I don't have to copy and paste each time I create a new handler class for a new XML.

For each file, I am only changing:

```
if(soap_read__gt__Library(&soap, &library) != SOAP_OK)
```

and

```
if(soap_write__gt__Library(&soap, &library) != SOAP_OK)
```

where gt is the namespace and Library is the root node.  Each new XML file will have a different namespace and root node.  These are now before compiling, is there anyway to automatically replace each class load/exportXML functions with their respected namespaces and root nodes?

e.g. I create a new xml with namespace test and rootnode devConfig.  I would like a method that replaces the load/exportXML with soap_read__test__devConfig and soap_write_test__devConfig.

```
void LoadXML(struct soap& soap, _gt__Library& library, const string& strXMLPath)
{
 ifstream fstreamIN(strXMLPath);
 soap.is = &fstreamIN;   

 // calls soap_begin_recv, soap_get__gt__Library and soap_end_recv
 if(soap_read__gt__Library(&soap, &library) != SOAP_OK)
 {
  std::cout << "soap_read__gt__Library() failed" << std::endl;
  throw 1;
 }

 // patch  
 if(_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_TEXT) == -1)
 {
  std::cout << "_setmode() failed" << std::endl;
  throw 1;
 }
 // ~patch  
}

void exportXML(struct soap& soap, _gt__Library& library, const string& strXMLPath)
{
 soap_set_omode(&soap, SOAP_XML_INDENT); 

 ofstream fstreamOUT(strXMLPath);
 soap.os = &fstreamOUT;

 // calls soap_begin_send, soap_serialize, soap_put and soap_end_send
 if(soap_write__gt__Library(&soap, &library) != SOAP_OK) 
 {
  std::cout << "soap_write__gt__Library() failed" << std::endl;      
  throw 1;
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but I suppose you could use a macro, like this:

```
#define loadXML(soap, gt_name, library, namespaces, root, strXMLPath) \
  ifstream fstreamIN(strXMLPath); \
  soap.is = &fstreamIN; \
  soap_set_namespaces(soap, namespaces); // namespace table \   
  if(soap_begin_recv(soap) || \
    soap_get_##gt_name(soap, library, root, NULL)) || \
    soap_end_recv(soap)) \
  { \
   std::cout << "soap_read__gt__Library() failed" << std::endl; \
   throw 1; \
  } \
  etc.
```

and expand it to implement the operations that you want:

```
loadXML(&soap, gt__library, &library, namespaces, "some-root", strXMLPath)
```